# Can I hide a specific option from ribon in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

[image]

Is that possible to hide a specific option from ribon using jquery or css. Suppose, I want hide edit and delete page.

Answer (score 0):

This blog might be help full to hide Ribbon button or group of ribbon.

http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/04/sharepoint-2010-hide-ribbon-button.html